# Efficient way to store and return custom CSS for personalised page visuals

Tags: html, css

I have a web app that needs to display pages whose CSS values are set via a form. To be clear: not the CSS parameters, just their values are user-defined.

I'm using a framework (jquery mobile). My css file is about 700 lines (the sass file is a little longer but full of comments and variables for colors, margins, etc). There are about a dozen variables inteded to be defined by the user (eg `$pageBackgroundColor`, `$borderWidth`, `$spanColor`), but each variable is used several times in the sass file.

Let's say I now have these dozen variables safely stored in my database, and a user requests a page. How do I provide the necessary CSS?

I could:

- compile a minified css file at the time of form submission and link
  it when a page is requested (downside: I'm likely to have several thousand CSS files sitting on my server)
- compile a minified css text string and dump it between two `<style>` tags in the `<head>` (downside: ugliness, no caching, and request handling time increases)

Are there any other options? I looked at one site that does custom visuals for each user and they went for a separate CSS file for each person.

I'm using a Django+Postgres backend, if it's relevant.

Comment: I have had this issue come up several times. What i usually do is create a set of predefined styles, so that the users themselves can choose from a set of styles.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need a higher degree of personalisation for colors and widgets and images (to be flexible enough to adhere to consumer brands' visual guidelines). Having a set menu of 5 or so styles would otherwise be great.

Comment: You can simply store those snippets in your database so that you do _not_ have thousands of individual files. Still you can reference them as external scripts, you just have to implement a router script handing over the database content as style script, which is trivial. This also allows caching of those snippets. So the best of both worlds.

Comment: This seems the opposite of the doctrine that says "store image paths, not blobs" though... I'd really like to keep the database clean by keeping blobs and compiled css out of it if possible...

Comment: If you are targeting mostly mobile devices, [consider CSS variables](http://caniuse.com/#search=variables)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went the giant composite heredoc external file route, with the file name saved in the db. It works well enough, but is obviously not fun to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the style declarations in which these variables are used to inline CSS, in the `<head>`. Additionally, you could do this with just a few styles, but it does require you to add more classes to your HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .user-background-color {
        background-color: #abc123;
     }
    .user-color {
        color: #abc123;
     }
    .user-border-color {
        border-color: #abc123;
     }
</style>
```

Then your HTML gets additional classes:

```
<div class="style-1 style-2 user-border-color"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not short or easy with JQM themeroller css. I'm presently waiting until the Jquery UI + JQM merger comes out to see if it's any better or if I'll eventually write my own widget framework as my project grows.

Comment: Fair enough. Best of luck!